# Meteor - return to client after successful login server-side

Tags: meteor

I wrote my custom method to login, but I'm blocked at the very last step: the effective login of the client.

I believe I'm correctly logged in server-side but no client side:

- I got full & correct (timestamp coherent) `LoginTokens` (`when` &
  `hashedToken`) in DB.
- In minimongo, I have access to all documents which I'm the owner of (`this.userId`).
- The login attempt `Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function (attempt)` is allowed, contains the right user and returns no error.
- On client, on call's return, `Meteor.loggingIn()` is `false` and `Meteor.user()` is `null`
- On server `Accounts.onLogin(function(user)` returns fine the `user._id`

So I assume it's an issue about the return to the client (like a user._id) - but I'm lost and think I need an experienced critic eye.

p.s.: I have accounts-base@1.4.0 & accounts-password@1.5.0

**Login method (called normally from client)**

```
Meteor.methods({

    logTwo (userfinal, passfinal) {
        
        // Consistency var check
        check(userfinal, String);
        const passwordValidator = {digest: String, algorithm: String};
        check(passfinal, passwordValidator);

        // check user
        const getUser = Accounts.findUserByEmail(userfinal);
        if (!getUser) {throw invalidLogin();}

        // check password
        const checkPassword = Accounts._checkPassword(getUser, passfinal);
        if (checkPassword.error) {throw invalidLogin();}

        // get user's id
        var userID = getUser._id

        // logic here
                
        console.log('code verified'); // rightly printed
        // below, I tried with or without methodArguments (this, 'login', {user: userfinal,password: passfinal},
        // and (this, 'login', '',
        Accounts._attemptLogin(this, 'login', {user: userfinal,password: passfinal}, {
            type: '2FALogin',
            userId: userID,
        });
    },
});

Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function (attempt) {
    console.log(attempt); // rightly printed

    if (attempt.type === '2FALogin' && attempt.methodName === 'login') {
        console.log('allowed'); // rightly printed
        return true;
    }

    if (attempt.error) {
        console.log('login error: ' + attempt.error);
    }

});
```

**return of Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function (attempt) (console.log(attempt))**

```
{ type: '2FALogin',
  allowed: true,
  methodName: 'login',
  methodArguments: 
   [ 'bob@bob.com',
     { digest: '70bd58ff28477...', // digest here ok
       algorithm: 'sha-256' } ],
  user: 
   { _id: '6i6vLjc8Ssg6SGJNf',
     createdAt: 2017-11-01T15:08:52.332Z,
     services: { password: [Object], resume: [Object] },
     emails: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     _loggedIn: true,
    },
  connection: 
   { id: 'xFLv3XZWztxsdxckM',
     close: [Function: close],
     onClose: [Function: onClose],
     clientAddress: '127.0.0.1',
     httpHeaders: 
      { 'x-forwarded-for': '127.0.0.1',
        'x-forwarded-proto': 'ws',
        host: 'localhost:3000',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36',
        'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,la;q=0.6' } } }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `Meteor.loginWithPassword` in the method when everything has validated? Also might be worth trying `this.setUserId` in the method?

Comment: I guess it is just a timing issue. I imagine that by the time your method callback is invoked, the user document was not yet published to the client and, therefore, not yet available.

Comment: @MasterAM so how to resolve it?

Comment: What do you need the `Meteor.user()` document for? Is it available to you later (e.g, from the console)?

Comment: It's not available even later. I think about Meteor.user() just to verify if the log is ok in the client.

Comment: @FredStark I tried with success, on your advices and because I have the userId, `Meteor.connection.setUserId(response);` on the method's return. When you mention 'in the method', you meant server-side? Can you be more specific, even response to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure how to manage it.

1. `Meteor.loginWithPassword` was not an option, as it's not working inside a `Meteor.call` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31901731/7281870)
2. I tried with success `Meteor.connection.setUserId(response)` on call's return, but nothing was stored in `localStorage`: so at every refresh, I was logged out.

I needed `Accounts.callLoginMethod`, from [accounts-base](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_client.js#L230):

> login method which on success calls `this.setUserId(id)` and
>   `Accounts._setLoginToken` on the server and returns an object with
>   fields `id` (containing the user id), `token` (containing a resume
>   token), and optionally `tokenExpires`.

Also, in the method, I needed to **return** the function `Accounts._attemptLogin` (or nothing could be handled by the client).

So, to resume:

**On client**

```
Accounts.callLoginMethod({
    methodName: 'logTwo',
    methodArguments: [
      {
        user: userfinal,
        password: passfinal
      },
    ],
    userCallback: function(error) {
      if (!error) {
        // handle return here
      } 
    }
});
```

**On server**

```
Meteor.methods({

    logTwo (options) {

        // Consistency var check
        const passwordValidator = {digest: String, algorithm: String};
        check(options, {
            user: String,
            password: passwordValidator
        });


        // check user
        const getUser = Accounts.findUserByEmail(options.user);
        if (!getUser) {throw invalidLogin();}

        // check password
        const checkPassword = Accounts._checkPassword(getUser, options.password);
        if (checkPassword.error) {throw invalidLogin();}

        // get user's id
        var userID = getUser._id

        // logic here

        return Accounts._attemptLogin(this, 'login', '', {
            type: '2FALogin',
            userId: userID,
        });
    },
});

Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function (options) {

    if (options.type === '2FALogin' && options.methodName === 'login') {
        return true;
    }

    if (options.error) {
        console.log('login error: ' + options.error);
    }

});
```

Comment: This stuff needs to be in the Meteor guide somewhere. Would you be willing to write a short section on implementing a custom login method? https://github.com/meteor/docs/

Comment: @FredStark You right, I will. But maybe the reason why `Accounts` functions are not in the docs, and generally so poorly documented, is because they can change without notice..